# The time it takes for PageMethod to be received by code behind is not consistent

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

I am quite new to webpage development.

I have a ASP .NET Web Application. On my webpage, I have several controls, that when clicked, will call a PageMethod to the code behind. My concern is, when I click any of these controls, and the respective PageMethod is fired, the amount of time it takes until the WebMethod in the code behind get hit is not consistent. Sometimes it will happen within 1s, but sometimes it will take 15s. The PageMethod always fires immediately after the click. It is not like these PageMethods are being called quickly either, so I wouldn't think any backup/lock is happening. I would like it so my PageMethods are always received by the code behind somewhere around 1s. I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue. I am hoping someone can explain/guide me to a solution. Below is a code snippet of one of these click instances:

Javascript side:

```
<canvas id="DisplayCanvas" onclick="onRadarEchoClick(event)"> </canvas>

    function onRadarEchoClick(e) {
                        //code stuff.
    
                        //Queue up radar echo click to be processed.
                        radarEchoQueue.push([convertedX, convertedY, e.button]);
        
                        var radarEchoInterval = setInterval(function () {
                            if (radarEchoReady) {
                                radarEchoReady = false;
                                clearInterval(radarEchoInterval);
                                const click = radarEchoQueue.shift();
                                PageMethods.OnRadarEchoClick(click[0], click[1], click[2], onRadarEchoSuccess);
                            }
                        }, 100);
                    }
        
                    function onRadarEchoSuccess() {
                        //The server has successfully processed the last radar echo click.
                        radarEchoReady = true;
                    }
```

Code behind side (C#):

```
    [WebMethod]
            public static void OnRadarEchoClick(double xComponent, double yComponent, int button)
            {
                //code stuff.
                //There is where my breakpoint will take a random amount of time (1-15s) to be hit.
            }
```

Comment: Is the delay in code behind,  or time to call the method? Calling a method is in general WELL UNDER  1/10th of a second. So if code behind called takes 10 seconds to run then that's code on server that's running slow. Time to call web methods is insignificant and as such is not an issue. Please post a working and reproduceable slow example

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal The delay is from when the PageMethod line is ran to when the WebMethod in the code behind is hit. I put a breakpoint right at the start of the WebMethod (before any server code in that WebMethod is ran). But if what you are saying is true. I’ll have to look to see if I can eliminate code processing that is heavy on the code behind side and see if things get better… But I wonder what is happening behind the scenes when PageMethods is being called. Is my client side code delaying the PageMethod from actually going out?

Comment: Try a jQuery. ajax call - time should be the same.  Drop in a test web method that returns hello. As I stated for this post please provide a working example.  This technology been around for 20 years and we don't find ANY post's on SO suggesting ANY performance issues in this area.  That being the case then you have to provide a sample that reproduces this issue, since everyone else is not experiencing your issue.